# How to generate and display new data-table based on row selection from existing datatable above using confirm selection button

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Save and Display datatable based on row selection from existing datatable

I need to display a datatable in r-shiny app and based on user's row selection (preferably using check box) and by clicking on confirm selection button, load and display data below in another databases (below the main table)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("Global Library", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        tabPanel("mtcars", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
        tabPanel("iris", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable3"))
      )
    )

)

library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # choose columns to display

  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data1, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE ,autoWidth=TRUE),filter = 'top')
  })

  # sorted columns are colored now because CSS are attached to them
  output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
  })

  # customize the length drop-down menu; display 5 rows per page by default
  output$mytable3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5,autoWidth=TRUE))
  })

}
```

I need to add button called save details below the table on first tab and need to create and display selected output below the button to display selected output from first table.

I am new to stackverflow, kindly help and please ignore extra code

Comment: Please edit your post with sample data and the code you have tried.

Comment: Code and description updated

Comment: Could anyone please can help me